# Apache automatically restarting itself every couple of requests

Tags: apache, xampp, restart

I just started having a problem where Apache will automatically restart after every few requests it receives. It's been working fine for a long time and I'm not sure why this would happen. The only thing I did recently was add an entry to my vhosts file to listen for another virtual host on the IP that it's running on. However, I reset that back to what it was and I'm still seeing the problem.

This is what the error.log shows:

```
[Fri Feb 12 16:29:12 2010] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 0 -- Restarting.
[Fri Feb 12 16:29:13 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.8 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_ssl/2.2.8 OpenSSL/0.9.8g mod_autoindex_color mod_auth_sspi/1.0.1 SVN/1.4.3 PHP/5.2.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Feb 12 16:29:13 2010] [notice] Server built: Jan 18 2008 00:37:19
[Fri Feb 12 16:29:13 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 6732
[Fri Feb 12 16:29:14 2010] [notice] Child 6732: Child process is running
[Fri Feb 12 16:29:14 2010] [notice] Child 6732: Acquired the start mutex.
[Fri Feb 12 16:29:14 2010] [notice] Child 6732: Starting 250 worker threads.
[Fri Feb 12 16:29:14 2010] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized
[Fri Feb 12 16:29:15 2010] [notice] Child 6732: Starting thread to listen on port 443.
[Fri Feb 12 16:29:15 2010] [notice] Child 6732: Starting thread to listen on port 82.
[Fri Feb 12 16:29:15 2010] [notice] Child 6732: Starting thread to listen on port 81.
[Fri Feb 12 16:29:15 2010] [notice] Child 6732: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Fri Feb 12 16:29:22 2010] [error] [client 192.168.3.12] (20024)The given path misformatted or contained invalid characters: Cannot map GET /wiki/index.php/Special:Random HTTP/1.1 to file, referer: http://review.laughlin.com:81/wiki/index.php/FullCircle
[Fri Feb 12 16:29:22 2010] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 0 -- Restarting.
[Fri Feb 12 16:29:23 2010] [notice] Apache/2.2.8 (Win32) DAV/2 mod_fastcgi/2.4.6 mod_ssl/2.2.8 OpenSSL/0.9.8g mod_autoindex_color mod_auth_sspi/1.0.1 SVN/1.4.3 PHP/5.2.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Feb 12 16:29:23 2010] [notice] Server built: Jan 18 2008 00:37:19
[Fri Feb 12 16:29:23 2010] [notice] Parent: Created child process 7252
[Fri Feb 12 16:29:24 2010] [notice] Child 7252: Child process is running
[Fri Feb 12 16:29:24 2010] [notice] Child 7252: Acquired the start mutex.
[Fri Feb 12 16:29:24 2010] [notice] Child 7252: Starting 250 worker threads.
[Fri Feb 12 16:29:24 2010] [notice] FastCGI: process manager initialized
[Fri Feb 12 16:29:24 2010] [notice] Child 7252: Starting thread to listen on port 443.
[Fri Feb 12 16:29:24 2010] [notice] Child 7252: Starting thread to listen on port 82.
[Fri Feb 12 16:29:24 2010] [notice] Child 7252: Starting thread to listen on port 81.
[Fri Feb 12 16:29:24 2010] [notice] Child 7252: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

I'm running it through XAMPP (not my preference, but was set up before me) and here are the versions it lists:

```
Apache 2.2.8
MySQL 5.0.51
PHP 5.2.5 + PHP 4.4.8 rc2 dev + PEAR
PHP-Switch win32 1.0 (please use the "php-switch.bat")
XAMPP Control Version 2.5 from www.nat32.com    
XAMPP Security 1.0  
SQLite 2.8.15
OpenSSL 0.9.8g
phpMyAdmin 2.11.4
ADOdb 4.96
Mercury Mail Transport System v4.52
FileZilla FTP Server 0.9.25
Webalizer 2.01-10
Zend Optimizer 3.3.0a
eAccelerator 0.9.5.2 for PHP 5.2.5  (comment out in the php.ini)
```

Does anyone know any reasons this could be happening? I've trying manually restarting the Apache service many times without luck. Also found some suggestions to replace the libmysql.dll or other files in the bin, but I haven't had any luck with that either.

The only other thing I've done recently on that server is trying to get PHP running in IIS (which was already running on the machine for a long time on a different IP, but I was just trying to enable PHP). I had no luck with that so I've now disabled the attempts I made.

Comment: So... is index.php/FullCircle redirecting to index.php/Special:Random? Seems like maybe it's expecting that to serve a random page but you've lost whatever was handling that Special, is that right? Possibly just a problem in the port 81 vhost - is that the one you added recently? Maybe something you think is global but is only in scope for another vhost. Maybe you can post some of the config...

Comment: I think Special:Random redirected to FullCircle or something. It's part of our wiki and I clicked on the 'Random Page' option, which is probably what's giving that message. It has nothing to do with that though because it's happening across all pages and all sites.

It's likely an issue on the port as I did add a second vhost on that port last week. A colleague of mine mentioned soon after I posted this that there is a port conflict, so that's probably the issue and we'll hopefully be looking into that today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was an interference from attempting to set up PHP in IIS as well on the same machine.